# What are the different nuances of saying 変{へん}?

Tags: word-choice, adverbs

I recently came across the term `変{へん}てこ`, which, if I understand it, means "strange", but is softer than saying `変{へん}な`.

Is it similar to `変{へん}なちょこ`? I think this also means strange, but also in a softer, possibly cute way.

In short, can someone clarify the different nuances of `変{へん}てこ`, `変{へん}な`, and `変{へん}なちょこ`?

Also, are there other examples of `～てこ`, or is it only used with `変{へん}`?

Comment: 変 is not an adverb.  I do not think that I have heard the word へんなちょこ, but if you are referring to へなちょこ, it means “poor (in quality).”

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`変てこ` is a shortened form of `変てこりん`, which seems to have underwent phonological change from `変ちくりん`. Not sure about the motivation of the sound change, but does not look unreasonable. The vowels in `ちく` changed:

> [iu] → [eo], which is:
> [+high, -back][+high, +back] → [-high, -back][-high, +back]

The origin of `ちくりん` is unknown, but is used with a few na-adjectives such as

> 変ちくりん
> 珍ちくりん
> 妙ちくりん

But be careful because some of them are politically incorrect.

`ちくりん` can be considered as a diminutive, adding cuteness. `変な` does not have that cuteness nuance. `変てこ`, `変てこりん`, and `変ちくりん` imply funny thing that is human made and cannot be used in a serious situation, whereas `変な` simply means strange or unusual.

> Scene: A doctor is doing a surgery, and finds an unusual thing in the patients body.
> In this case, the doctor can say `変なものがある`, but definetely not `変てこなものがある`.
>
> Scene: There is a painting on the wall, which is commical and fun but nothing wrong.
> In this case, although `変な絵がある` is not impossible, `変てこな絵がある` will be a better fit.

As Tsuyoshi Ito mentions in the comment, `へなちょこ` means poor in quality. It does not mean strange.